# In gtsummary, is there a way to add add_n() on the side of the variable's label? (instead of in a new column)

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to add something like a (N = {N}) next to the name of each variable but in the same column, is there any default option for this?

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% select(mpg, disp, vs) %>% tbl_summary() %>% add_n()
```

[image: here is an example of what i would like to do]

I looked for a solution on the package's official website but didn't find anything (english is not my native language :/)

Comment: After you run add_n(), you can try merging the first label column with the n column with modify_column_merge()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a way in that exists in `gtsummary`, but you could make a little function that would do it for you:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
add_n_name <- function(.data, ...){
  nv <- apply(.data, 2, function(x)sum(!is.na(x)))
  newnames <- paste(colnames(.data), " (N=", nv, ")", sep="")
  setNames(.data, newnames)
}
```

The function `add_n_name()`, takes the data, calculates the number of non-missing observations for each variable, creates new names by pasting `(N={N})` to the variable name and then sets the names of the dataset to these new names that contain N.  Stick this in your pipeline after you select the variables you are going to use:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, vs) %>% 
  add_n_name() %>%   
  tbl_summary()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>